# Switching DOM elements positions arbitrarily

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a responsive website that changes widgets' position arbitrarily upon being viewed in different viewport widths.

Visually, its turning this:

[image: big]

Into this:

[image: small]

My first approach was setting placeholder div elements in this way:

```
<div data-change-from=".my-element"></div>
```

And using [response.js](http://responsejs.com/) to detect widths and move elements around with jQuery, but with complex grids and more widgets it has become unmanageable.

What is an efficient and reliable way to do this ?

Comment: Ever thought about isotope (link [here](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)) or masonry (link [here](http://masonry.desandro.com/)), they both do this sort of thing

Answer (score 1):

## Use CSS

It's great and does all things.

```
body { position: relative }
body:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
#one, #two, #three, #four, #five, #six {
    height: 40px;
    background: #aaa;
    margin: 8px 1%;
    float: right;
}
#one-two {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 45%;
}
#one, #two { width: 100% }
#three, #four, #five, #six {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
#five, #six { width: 50% }
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    #one-two {
        position: static;
        display: inline;
    }
    #one, #three, #five {
        width: 60%;
        float: left;
    }
    #two, #four, #six {
        width: 35%;
        float: right;
    }
}
```

Requires only one extra container:

```
<div id="one-two">
    <div id="two">2</div>
    <div id="one">1</div>
</div>
<div id="three">3</div>
<div id="four">4</div>
<div id="five">5</div>
<div id="six">6</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nce9b/

Basically I have a default style that's applied unless overridden in the media query `(min-width: 1000px)`. This rearranges the elements by adjusting floats, widths, and in the case of `#one` and `#two` applying `position: absolute` (to move it to the bottom). When the window is big enough, the media query overrides the styles forming a nice simple grid.

Comment: Note the colors on the images. Same color boxes are actually the same html elements.